# What styles need to be added to the card so that each element in the card takes up as much height as there is in the content?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKGSg.png)

It is necessary for the elements of the card tags, title, author to occupy as much height as the content in the element. It is important that the cards are similar in size. Can you help me with this problem?

```
    <div class="card__list">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card__tags">
          tags tags tags tags tags tags tags tags tags tags tags tags
        </div>
        <div class="card__title">
          title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title
        </div>
        <div class="card__line"></div>
        <div class="card__author">
          author
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card__tags">
          tags
        </div>
        <div class="card__title">
          title
        </div>
        <div class="card__line"></div>
        <div class="card__author">
          author
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card__tags">
          tags
        </div>
        <div class="card__title">
          title
        </div>
        <div class="card__line"></div>
        <div class="card__author">
          author
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```
.card__list {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 200px);
}

.card {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr auto 1fr;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.card__tags {
  background: lightyellow;
}

.card__title {
  background: lightblue;
}

.card__line {
  height: 2px;
  background: pink;
}

.card__author {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

I only got as far as grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr auto 1fr for card(